# What the differences between adding a new label in TFS and adding a label to a label

Tags: tfs

In TFS it's possible to add a new label to a code branch and by default all files and folders below that level get the label.  If I wanted to rename that label I could delete it and add another label with the new name.  Alternatively I can add a label to the original label then delete the original lable.

What is the difference between the two as the end result seems to be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the difference between the two as the end result seems to be the same.

Correct: no difference.

A label is set against a set of specific versions of files.

Another label is just another way (like "latest" or "my workspace") of selecting the version of the files being labelled. (Not including label for this purpose would mean special casing setting of labels to having a slightly different set of version selection criteria.)